# Menu block Issue while using with multiligual i18n module install

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n, blocks

I've installed the [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module (to display 2-level menus in page side bar etc) and the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module to create a multilingual site.

But when I translate the content in other languages say content in Italian, and come back to view and click on Italian view of page the Menu-Block goes hide.

I assume that it is due to 'it' into the URL (like http://example.com/node/4/it/). How to fix this issue. Kindly help. i'll appreciate. thanks

Comment: did u enabled menu transalation in i18n package..??